# Spring Modulith - ApplicationModuleTest with JPA repositories in different modules

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-data-jpa, spring-modulith

While working with Spring Modulith I am trying to test the ApplicationModuleTest in a multi module application. I am running into problems when spring is trying to create JpaRepositories implementations for modules that are not under test.

My project structure is as follows:

> nl.daniel.dejong
>
> - Application.java
> - inventorymanagement
>
>   - domain
>
>     - ProductService.java
>     - Product.java
>     - ProductId.java
>   - infrastructure.persistence
>
>     - ProductJpaPersistence.java
> - orderfulfillment
>
>   - domain
>
>     - OutboundOrder.java
>   - infrastructure.persistence
>
>     - OutboundOrderJpaPersistence.java

The persistences are default JpaPersistences using the domain object as domain object eg:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductJpaPersistence extends ProductPersistence, JpaRepository<Product, ProductId> {
}
```

My Application.java looks as follows

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class Application {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

When creating a `ApplicationModuleTest` for the product module It is trying to create a `OutboundOrderJpaPersistence` bean. The results into the problem that the ApplicationModuleTest annotation filters the scope of the test and therefor it cannot find the OutboundOrder that the Repository is managing.

Test:

```
@ApplicationModuleTest
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class ProductIntegrationTest {
    private static final String PRODUCT_NAME = "Product 1";
    private final ProductService productService;

    @Test
    public void createProduct(Scenario scenario) {
        var createProduct = new Product();
        createProduct.setName(PRODUCT_NAME);

        scenario.stimulate(() -> productService.create(createProduct))
                .andWaitForEventOfType(ProductCreated.class)
                .matchingMappedValue(ProductCreated::name, PRODUCT_NAME);

    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Failed to resolve parameter [final nl.daniel.dejong.inventorymanagement.application.product.ProductService productService] in constructor [public nl.daniel.dejong.inventorymanagement.ProductIntegrationTest(nl.daniel.dejong.inventorymanagement.application.product.ProductService)]: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@6ed000ba testClass = nl.daniel.dejong.inventorymanagement.ProductIntegrationTest, locations = [], classes = [nl.daniel.dejong.Application], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [[ImportsContextCustomizer@5862dc47 key = [org.springframework.modulith.test.ModuleTestAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@7857fe2, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@446a1e84, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@626abbd0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@37313c84, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@415b0b49, org.springframework.modulith.test.ModuleContextCustomizerFactory$ModuleContextCustomizer@17503f8a, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@ab9d71ae], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ParameterResolutionUtils.resolveParameter(ParameterResolutionUtils.java:159)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ParameterResolutionUtils.resolveParameters(ParameterResolutionUtils.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:59)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:310)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:286)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$before$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:203)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@6ed000ba testClass = nl.daniel.dejong.inventorymanagement.ProductIntegrationTest, locations = [], classes = [nl.daniel.dejong.Application], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [[ImportsContextCustomizer@5862dc47 key = [org.springframework.modulith.test.ModuleTestAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@7857fe2, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@446a1e84, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@626abbd0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@37313c84, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@415b0b49, org.springframework.modulith.test.ModuleContextCustomizerFactory$ModuleContextCustomizer@17503f8a, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@ab9d71ae], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(SpringExtension.java:283)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.resolveParameter(SpringExtension.java:269)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ParameterResolutionUtils.resolveParameter(ParameterResolutionUtils.java:136)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'outboundOrderJpaPersistence' defined in nl.daniel.dejong.orderfulfillment.infrastructure.persistence.OutboundOrderJpaPersistence defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on Application: Not a managed type: class nl.daniel.dejong.orderfulfillment.domain.order.OutboundOrder
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1406)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:119)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class nl.daniel.dejong.orderfulfillment.domain.order.OutboundOrder
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)
    ... 76 more
```

When changing the `@EnableJpaRepositories` to point to the module under test `@EnableJpaRepositories("nl.daniel.dejong.inventorymanagement")` the test works as expected.

PS: The situation described above is a representation as close as possible to the full implementation, but it could miss some information. Left out some of the details to not cloud the post.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this unexpected behavior?

Edit: by actually removing the ‘EnableJpaRepositories’ from the ‘Application.Java’ I am able to override the repository locations by using a configuration containing ‘EnableJpaRepositories’ in the test. I am still of opinion that SpringModulith should have a way of doing this by itself.

Comment: How do you configure modulith, so that your domain classes in every module can live in a `domain` subpackage? When running `org.springframework.modulith.core.ApplicationModules#verify` I get `Duplicate key domain (attempted merging values # Domain ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion with the maintainer of the spring-modulith it has been resolved in a later version. This version is of not yet fully released by spring.

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-modulith/issues/316 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `@EnableJpaRepositories` will look for all repositories defined in the project including `OutboundOrderJpaPersistence` to initialize them as Spring beans. However, the `@ApplicationModuleTest` annotation by default will import [only the module under test](https://docs.spring.io/spring-modulith/docs/current/reference/html/#testing.bootstrap-modes) which will exclude `orderfulfillment` module which contains `OutboundOrderJpaPersistence`. As a result the application crashes.

You have several options here:

1. Add `@SpringBootTest` and `@EnableScenarios` annotations to the test class.
2. Use `@ApplicationModuleTest(extraIncludes = "orderfulfillment")` - not recommended because as soon as you add another repository which `inventorymanagement` doesn't depend on, you will run into the same issue again.
3. In case `inventorymanagement` module depends on `orderfulfillment` then you could use `@ApplicationModuleTest(ApplicationModuleTest.BootstrapMode.DIRECT_DEPENDENCIES)` but I wouldn't recommend this because as soon as you add another repository which `inventorymanagement` doesn't depend on, you will run into the same issue again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think the solution should be in a way where we can exclude the repository from being included while in the ApplicationModuleTest instead of expanding the scope. The goal of this test is to have a scoped test, we should not break that. Sadly I am not able to find a way yet to configure my  test in this way.

Comment: Your logic is right, but Spring Modulith doesn't give a solution for this problem which is really a Spring Boot problem. There're probably some complicated workarounds which are either not worth the effort or which will not hold for a real project. Perhaps check Spring Boot slices https://spring.io/blog/2016/08/30/custom-test-slice-with-spring-boot-1-4